Rmd Officedown: Cannot get the table of contents to show up
I have tried several permutations and example code from other questions, but no matter what I try I cannot get a table of contents to appear when using officedown. I can get it to appear when using regular Rmarkdown output, but I would like to use officedown for other reasons. How do I get a table of contents to appear? I am using pandoc 3.1.11
Sample Code:
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_depth: 3
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown)
library(officer)

```

# Table of contents
```{r, echo=FALSE}
block_toc(level = 3)
```
# Title
## Subtitle

This is my output when rendered

Have you clicked "yes" when asked to "update fields" when opening the docx? That's what I get when I do so: https://i.sstatic.net/FE2c9GVo.png. Also note that using both block_toc() and adding the toc via the YAML will add 2 tocs.

this linksuggests you can make a style reference sheet, and then when rendering the doc, pass in the formated TOC word doc.
